# SQLite select query foreach through column

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

how to run this query for each mat in gain table
and get result together
X: mat from gain table

```
with gain_v as ( SELECT * from gain where mat = X ) 
SELECT * from gain_v
```

Comment: SQLite does not support a foreach statement. You have tagged `android-sqlite`. So you can do it with Java.

Comment: @forpas
it will take alot of time in java

Comment: Maybe, but it is not doable with SQLite only. Or maybe you did not explain clearly what you want. Edit your question and provide sample data and expected results.